# How to save iotop's output for a specific period of time

Tags: io

I am trying to discern what processes are making huge Read/Writes on my server disk. I know I can use

```
iotop -ao
```

but is there a way I can save iotop's output for a specific period of time to study later?

Comment: i would use a cronjob to fire it up, put it in the background, and kill it after $X seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't strictly answering your question, but you might find `atop` more useful.  It can run as a daemon and write to a binary log file.  The file contains all data necessary to reproduce what would have been seen had `atop` been run 'live'.

To run `atop` as a daemon, you could kick it off as

```
/usr/bin/atop -a -w /var/log/atop.log 60
```

to write a snapshot to the log every 60 seconds.  Later you can see what was going on at a specific time by doing e.g.

```
atop -r /var/log/atop.log -b 10:00
```

to start at 10am.  You can then step backwards and forwards throught the log to see how system activity developed.

To address your specific question of disk activity, pressing `d` while in `atop` will sort processes by their total disk activity at that point in time, and in the summary at the top of the screen you'll be able to see aggregated per-device statistics.